# Google App Store: How to test subscription?

Tags: android, flutter, google-play

I have released my first alpha version in the Google play console. I have added my email address I use on my Android phone as a tester. I created a subscription that is currently active, which I'm now trying to test.

When I query my productsDetails with the productId, it won't find them.

I'm using the `in_app_purchase` package any I'm querying like this:

```
final products = await InAppPurchaseConnection.instance.queryProductDetails(productIds);
```

I just installed the apk, that I uploaded on the Google play console on my device. Is that the intended way?

Any ideas? How do I test Google Play Subscriptions the right way?

Comment: Have you completed reviewed the documentation on this matter? https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing

Comment: @dominicoder yes I did, but I'm still not quite sure, if testing will only work if I download the app over the appstore or if I can just run the app in debug mode from my IDE?

Comment: You should be able to run the app in the IDE after uploading a version with the Billing SDK to the Google Play store alpha / testing track.